# ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed in jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am using mvn test command to run selenium test cases using chrome and chrome driver with same versions on ubuntu 20.04.
When I run mvn test command in terminal it works fine in the directory build was successful.
When I run mvn test command in jenkins pipeline it gives me error

```
> [ERROR] initialization(LogInCases)  Time elapsed: 2.525 s  <<<
> FAILURE! org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:  Could not
> start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome
> failed to start: crashed.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
> doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
> /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
> assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

My jenkins pipeline stage command is

```
sh 'cd home/useradmin/files/ && mvn test'
```

How to fix this so that I can get the same result in a machine terminal as in jenkins pipeline.